# How can I check information about the nodes in Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I loaded SSDlite_coco Model on Tensorboard to study its structure.

But when I see the ClassPredictor_Depthwise part, there is some FusedBatchNorm's nodes.

I want to know what these is, and where they are come from.

I just started study TensorFlow, so please understand my basic Questions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrbsL.png)

Comment: I am going to assume that those are the variables contained by all batch norm layers since there are four nodes. These are the `beta`, `gamma`, `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` properties.

Comment: thanks for answer! then is there any way that I can check where those properties come from?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorboard provides the Graph dashboard to examining Tensorflow model. One can verify the conceptual graph of the model and to match intended design.
Take a look at the details about nodes [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#op-level_graph).